# Unable to get value from HTML view to controller using Angular. Solution returns $scope variable undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi guys im trying to get some input from a text field using angular ng-bind and get access to it in the controller. Currently when i try to print it out i get undefined. Would appreciate some help im sure im missing something from my set up.

This is my HTML

```
    <div class="text-center rounded-box" ng-app="AuthorisationTicketApp" ng-controller="LookupTicketController">
<form>

    <b>Please insert text:</b>
    <input type="text" name="text" ng-bind="text" />
</form>

<div class="lg-margin-top">
    <a href="#lookup-ticket" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit</a>
</div>
```

My controller

```
authorisationTicketApp.controller('LookupTicketController', ['$scope', 
function($scope) {

console.log('LookupTicketController .... called');

console.log('text' + $scope.text);
console.log('$scope ' + $scope);

}]);
```

My app.js

```
var authorisationTicketApp = angular.module('AuthorisationTicketApp', ['ngRoute']);

authorisationTicketApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/input-text', {
    templateUrl: contextPath + 'partials/input-text.html',
    controller: 'LookupTicketController'
}).
when('/lookup-ticket', {
        templateUrl: contextPath + 'partials/lookup-ticket.html',
        controller: 'LookupTicketController'
}).
otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});
```

}]);

My console output

```
LookupTicketController .... called controllers.js:11:1
$ text undefined controllers.js:13:1
$scope [object Object]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `ng-model` on your input tag instead of `ng-bind`.  This will two-way bind to the value in the controller:

```
<input type="text" name="text" ng-model="text" />
```

Comment: Just to be clear. I used ng-bind because i didnt want two way binding. The main objective is to get the variable from the input field to my spring controller rest method.

Comment: You still need to get the value into your controller to send it to the REST endpoint.  This would be the idiomatic way to read a value from an input and send to an endpoint in Anguar

Comment: changing to ng-model does not fix the solution. Maybe its lacking something else. Tbh im very new to this framework so would appreciate any more pointers

Comment: What is the issue?  Is $scope.text still undefined?

Comment: Yes either that or i log the actual function which is trying to access the data value

Comment: Does your controller code still look like it does above?  Because you are logging the text during the initialization if so.  That means at the time you're logging, the text isn't yet set.  You'd have to log the value of text in a clickhandler or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the documentation:

> Use controllers to:
>         * Set up the initial state of the $scope object.

Do not use it to log anything. It should only contain the business logic. Construct it by:

```
authorisationTicketApp.controller('LookupTicketController', ['$scope', 
function($scope) {

$scope.text = "test";
console.log('LookupTicketController .... called');

}]);
```

Then it should work.

Comment: The state of the scope object should only be set by the whatever is entered into the input field.

Answer (score 0):

All of your controller code is constructor code and the text property does not exist at the time of construction. You'll want a method that you call elsewhere after construction that you can create with $scope.myMethod = function() {...} and you should be able to reference $scope.text from within there. It's also a good practice to initialize the text property with $scope.text = '' in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, Please have a look by using ng-model

```
<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-content>
        <input class="form-input" type="text" ng-model="test.relation"/>
        <button class="button button-bar button-positive" ng-click="answer()">Click Me</button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Inside your controller please update your code as:

```
$scope.test = {};
$scope.answer = function(){
    console.log($scope.test.relation);
}
```

Please reply back, if you have any queries..

Comment: It doesnt look right for me Anil

I need my solution to work. If i work with another solution which introduces new variables then i will still have to reverse engineer it to get back to my simple solution

Comment: your solution throws a ng:areq Bad Argument exception when i tried it